# Split time series with multiple records per day

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation

I have a dataset of daily transactions where there are multiple records per day. I need to split it into different cross validation folds to train a ML model, however I can't user TimeSeriesSplit from sklearn as there are multiple transactions per day. Do you know how can I do this in python?

Comment: If the records are ordered by time-stamp, in principle you could still use `TimeSeriesSplit`, after ordering by time-stamp... you would have records from the same day in both training and test, but the important thing is that the records in the training set have a time-stamp lower than those in test set.  If you want to avoid to have records from the same day in training and test, then: if the number of records per day is constant you can still use `TimeSeriesSplit`. If it is variable, you can transform days into tuples, pass a list of tuples to `TimeSeriesSplit`, and then convert back?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But then how can I control the test size? I want to implement a rolling window approach. Hence I need to keep the transactions for each day separated from each other

Comment: Could you please provide a small example of input data and desired output? That would help clarify your problem and come up with a solution.

Comment: `import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['DAY_1','afds',5], ['DAY_1','rtws', 4], ['DAY_1','gtssd', 2], ['DAY_2','ititl', 4], 
                 ['DAY_2','uius', 7], ['DAY_3','hyaah', 6], ['DAY_4','apsaj', 9]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['DATEDAY','TRANSACTION_ID','PRICE'])
df`

Comment: So considering that example, I need to use rows from DAY_1 and DAY_2 to train and then test with DAY_3. Then use DAY_1, DAY_2 and DAY_3 to train, testing with DAY_4. Thank you for your help @JauA

Comment: Thanks @andyolivers, I just posted a solution to this problem. You might want to edit your question to include the example you gave me, in order to make it more clear for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array(
    [['DAY_1','afds',5],
     ['DAY_1','rtws', 4],
     ['DAY_1','gtssd', 2],
     ['DAY_2','ititl', 4],
     ['DAY_2','uius', 7],
     ['DAY_3','hyaah', 6],
     ['DAY_4','apsaj', 9]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['DATEDAY','TRANSACTION_ID','PRICE'])
```

Resulting df:

```py
        TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
DATEDAY
DAY_1             afds     5
DAY_1             rtws     4
DAY_1            gtssd     2
DAY_2            ititl     4
DAY_2             uius     7
DAY_3            hyaah     6
DAY_4            apsaj     9
```

Solution:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

df = df.set_index('DATEDAY')
days = np.sort(df.index.unique())
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(2)
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(days):
    print ('------------------------------')
    train_days, test_days = days[train_index], days[test_index]
    X_train, X_test = df.loc[train_days], df.loc[test_days]
    print ('train:', X_train, '\n')
    print ('test:', X_test, '\n')
```

Output:

```py
------------------------------
train:         TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
DATEDAY
DAY_1             afds     5
DAY_1             rtws     4
DAY_1            gtssd     2
DAY_2            ititl     4
DAY_2             uius     7

test:         TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
DATEDAY
DAY_3            hyaah     6

------------------------------
train:         TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
DATEDAY
DAY_1             afds     5
DAY_1             rtws     4
DAY_1            gtssd     2
DAY_2            ititl     4
DAY_2             uius     7
DAY_3            hyaah     6

test:         TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
DATEDAY
DAY_4            apsaj     9
```

> Note 1: we assume that the date column can be sorted. In this example, `DAY_X` doesn't sort well, since DAY_11 would be placed before DAY_2, for instance. If we only know the number `X` of the day, then we need to put `X` in the column, instead of `DAY_X`, e.g., we might do something like:

```
df['DATEDAY'] = [int(x.split('_')[1]) for x in df['DATEDAY']]
```

> Note 2: if we want to avoid having `DATEDAY` as index of the dataframe, we can simply reset the index for `X_train` and `X_test`:

```py
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(days):
    print ('------------------------------')
    train_days, test_days = days[train_index], days[test_index]
    X_train, X_test = df.loc[train_days].reset_index(), df.loc[test_days].reset_index()
    print ('train:\n', X_train, '\n')
    print ('test:\n', X_test, '\n')
```

Output:

```py
------------------------------
train:
   DATEDAY TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
0   DAY_1           afds     5
1   DAY_1           rtws     4
2   DAY_1          gtssd     2
3   DAY_2          ititl     4
4   DAY_2           uius     7

test:
   DATEDAY TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
0   DAY_3          hyaah     6

------------------------------
train:
   DATEDAY TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
0   DAY_1           afds     5
1   DAY_1           rtws     4
2   DAY_1          gtssd     2
3   DAY_2          ititl     4
4   DAY_2           uius     7
5   DAY_3          hyaah     6

test:
   DATEDAY TRANSACTION_ID PRICE
0   DAY_4          apsaj     9
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it!

Comment: Apologies from my side. I am new here and thought I had to tag it again as unresolved. Anyway, up to you and once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: In order to change the number of days per split, you need to change the parameter `n_splits` passed to `TimeSeriesSplit`, in the statement: `tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(2)` (see the documentation of `TimeSeriesSplit` in sklearn site).  Here, I used the value 2 to obtain the output you indicated. In general, if you want to have X% of the total number of days in your test set, you pass n_splits=1/X. For example, if you want 20% of the days in the test set and 80% in the training set, then you pass n_splits=1/0.2=5, and so on.

Comment: Thank you do much! It works perfectly, I would upvote this, but can't as I need 15 reputation points btw 

Comment: How can this tscv be used with GridSearchCV? Unique index is needed for the search object.